# How do I rename files sequentially in automator based on a variable?

Tags: automator

I'd like to rename some image files. Is there a way to have the service ask what number to start at?

[image]

Everything here is set up as I'd like it to be. Though, when I run the script, I would like the service to ask me for a variable and then input it into the "start numbers at" box.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: If I may, you can do this much simpler by highlighting those files in the Finder and right-clicking on one of them. Notice how the *Rename* option has changed to *Rename x Files* (*x* being the number of selected files). There is an option there for you to do exactly what you are trying to produce in Automator, in my opinion, using the Finder is not only faster but much simpler. Is that something you have considered using?

Comment: 1. You have not stated what type of Automator workflow this is a part of. 2. You have not stated if this is the only action in the workflow. 3. Is there some reason you just cannot check the "Show this action when the workflow runs" check box, so you can then set the "Start numbers at" field at that time!?

Comment: @ProGrammer, Aside from the fact, that option (Rename n Items...) is not available in all versions of OS X/macOS in Finder, where it is available "Make Sequential" isn't an option.

Comment: Rename x Files did not appear in my version of macOS. I didn't think about the show this action when it runs. This did what I need it to do. Thank you.

Comment: @user3439894 This option is not a single selection but can be produced in a two-step process with the built-in tool. Just a thought... if you need more advanced formatting and renaming, just take a look at Better Finder Rename (http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/version10.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked "Show this action when the workflow runs".

This allows me to choose what number to start at.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good idea.  "Rename x files" does indeed appear in my Finder (MacOS Catalina 10.15.7), but seems to be of limited use: there doesn't seem to be a way to preserve the original name nor control the number of digits in the sequence number (using the "Format" option, all the files come out like `1 File.jpg` instead of `01 Start the engine.jpg`). To make this Automator workflow appear in Finder's *File > Services* context menu, had to a) save it in `~/Library/Services`, and b) save it as type `Quick Action` (using *File > Convert to*).  NB when you do that, the name still ends in `.workflow` despite now not being a "Workflow".